# Background Threads and Dialogs

Tags: c#

I have a small program that starts as an appbar (a window which docks to the desktop and can be hidden (on the top, right, bottom, or left side of the desktop when not in use). The program permits a user to drag a file (or files) from any given location on to the appbar and convert it to PDF (by converting each file to PDF and then merging the resulting PDF's into a single PDF file).

The conversion process runs on a seperate thread using a backgroundworker. Once the backgroundworker acquires the list of files, I have a modal dialog which pops up, having loaded a listview with the relevant files, and allows the user to reorder them prior to the final merge process.

I am having cross-thread issues with the modal dialog. I have searched high and low for a solution, but am stumped. The problems arises as a result of the use of the keyword this.

I have tried the following code in the midst of the backgroundworker:

```
using (var md = new MergeDlg())
{
    md.Files = (string[])files;
    if (md.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        files = md.Files;
}
```

If I remove the keyword *this* I get no error, but the dialog behaves as if it is started on the main thread and the backgroundworkerthread continues as if there is no modal dialog - I understand that ***is*** because the dialog is started on the main UI thread.

I have also tried moving the dialog creation out of the background worker thread and calling it in the thread
the code to create the modal dialog is as follows:

```
private string[] ShowMergeDlg(string[] files)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            MergeDlg md = new MergeDlg();
            md.Files = (string[])files;
            if (md.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                files = md.Files;
        }
        ));
    }
    else
    {
        MergeDlg md = new MergeDlg();
        md.Files = (string[])files;
        if (md.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            files = md.Files;
    }

    return files;
}
```

On the backgroundworker thread, the function is called:

```
files = ShowMergeDlg(files);
```

Again that code obviously starts the dialog on the main UI thread with the same result.

My question is then:

How do I show a modal dialog on a backgroundworker thread, pausing execution of the thread until such times as the modal dialog has been closed?

Comment: Pausing a thread has to be cooperative-- the code running on the thread needs to agree to pause. So the way to accomplish this depends on what that worker thread is doing, e.g. if it is executing a loop it could check a flag at the beginning of each iteration. What is the worker thread doing, exactly?

Comment: Do you *need* to do the file enumeration on the background thread? It is called a `BackgroundWorker` because it is designed to run background tasks. If you need to report information to the main thread you are supposed to set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to `true`, and raise the `ProgressChanged` event through calling the `ReportProgress()` method. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: However in your case you are just enumerating files and showing a dialog, why do you need to do that in the background? Surely the merge itself is what you want to execute in the background. If you want to speed up the enumeration, you should be adding threading code to the dialog itself, not the calling code.

Comment: The reason the backgroundworker thread is being used, is that there is a lot of conversion work going on at the beginning of the process, so for example, if an eml or msg file is dragged from Outlook or a directory - that email file could contain a series of  attachments - each one of those attachments, then needs to be parsed from the email &converted before the list is populated ...  the code for all of that parsing & conversion is there & working fine - however it has now been suggested that the user should have the ability to re-order the files prior to merging - thus the dialog list

Comment: Sounds like a job for tasks / async await, it would save your self a lot of hassle

Comment: My question stands, why are you doing this on the secondary thread? If you drag and drop something in your app, a handler in the form is first to get it. Just show your dialog there, *before* passing the message to the parser/converter/merger running on the backgroundworker...

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey ... because it is the parsing of the email that can be intensive (if its only a couple of attachments its not, but many of the emails that will be converted have any number of attachments) and it is that part of the process that yields the files to be converted  ... I have thought about splitting the process into 3 steps - 1 parse the email and get the list of files - convert them and then allow the user to reorder the files prior to the final merge but it would be double handling ... is there a way to do it in the same thread ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall ... I found an article https://sriramsakthivel.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/asynchronous-showdialog/ which talks about tasks/async wait and a modal dialog - if that is what you are referring to - how would I pass the list of files to a dialog created in that manner and retrieve the modified list?

Comment: @DWE No, it is like `var files = await AquireFilesAsync(); files = ShowMergeDialog( files ); await ProcessFilesAsync( files );`

Comment: @SirRufo ... would you elaborate and provide a code snippet (skeletal) of how you would implement your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You better switch to async/await and Tasks. Here a very limited sample

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;

        label1.Text = "acquire files ...";
        ICollection<string> acquiredFiles = await AcquireFileAsync();

        label1.Text = "select files ...";
        ICollection<string> selectedFiles = SelectFilesDialog( acquiredFiles );

        label1.Text = "process files ...";
        await ProcessFilesAsync( selectedFiles );

        label1.Text = "finished.";
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async Task ProcessFilesAsync( ICollection<string> selectedFiles )
    {
        foreach (var item in selectedFiles)
        {
            await Task.Delay( 250 ).ConfigureAwait( false );
        }
    }

    private ICollection<string> SelectFilesDialog( ICollection<string> acquiredFiles )
    {
        var dialog = new Form2();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        return acquiredFiles;
    }

    private async Task<ICollection<string>> AcquireFileAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay( 2500 ).ConfigureAwait( false );
        return Enumerable.Range( 1, 20 ).Select( e => e.ToString() ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `ShowMergeDlg` from the background worker, `InvokeRequired` will be true, then the dialog creates on the UI thread. So just remove it, let the dialog create on the background thread.

```csharp
private string[] ShowMergeDlg(string[] files)
{
    /*
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            MergeDlg md = new MergeDlg();
            md.Files = (string[])files;
            if (md.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                files = md.Files;
        }
        ));
    }
    else
    */
    {
        MergeDlg md = new MergeDlg();
        md.Files = (string[])files;
        if (md.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            files = md.Files;
    }

    return files;
}
```

---

**My test code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText("1")));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        var f2 = new Form2();
        if(f2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText("2")));
        else
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText("3")));

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText("1")));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: the inclusion of the keyword "this" causes the cross thread exception ...

Comment: Are your sure the problem is rasied by `ShowDialog` method? as I test on my computer, there is no exception.

Comment: Thanks for submitting that bit of code - but I think your missing my point - in my code (exactly the same as above) the same cross threading error still occurs .. see ...  https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx5zpc8g2sbpaht/example.png?dl=0